# How do i find location of a wpf element in a window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, location, coded-ui-tests

I need to be able to find the location of a WPF element on an application window so i can then draw a rectangle around the specific element on a screenshot/image capture of the window containing this element.

This is for a VS Coded UI Framework i am developing that has window captures or element capture to an image when an error occurs. I want to combine these two and have a window capture that shows a red rectangle around the element in error.

Alot of forums have answers around this, but they refer to **TranslatePoint**. I cannot see this when working with Visual Studio and Microsofts UITesting Coded UI WpfControls. Anyone know how to get around this??

Answer (score 0):

[TranslatePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx) is defined on `UIElement`.  Any `UIElement` should expose this.

I suspect the problem is that WpfControl is not a WPF `UIElement`. You should be able to use it's [BoundedRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.uitestcontrol.boundingrectangle.aspx) property to get the proper surrounding rectangle instead of TranslatePoint on a`UIElement`.

Comment: Thanks for that Reed. So i have played around a little bit and found BoundedRectangle - Location returns coordinates in relation to the whole screen, not the window that the object is on. So i have figured out that i will need to get the coordinates of the object and the window and find the difference to get the placement of the red rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Never use coordinates. Instead, get the control and use the `DrawHighlight()` method. This will draw a blue rectangle outside the control.

Comment: Please don't include 'closings' and signatures in your posts.

Comment: I'm not sure DrawHighlight is a standard WPF method.  I think you are getting that from some third-party toolkit.